# Learning algorithm to implement XOR gate

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, xor, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

I know we can't use perceptron learning algorithm to implement XOR gate because it is a lineraly inseparable problem. So my question is which learning algorithm and which neural network can we use to implement XOR gate? I tried using Delta rule, but it is not producing desired weight matrix.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2 layered MLP (multi-layer perceptron) will do the trick.

Consider [this article](https://medium.com/@jayeshbahire/the-xor-problem-in-neural-networks-50006411840b).

By the way, Wikipedia reads:

> The delta rule is a gradient descent learning rule for updating the
> weights of the inputs to artificial neurons in a single-layer neural
> network.

The "single-layer neural network" here is the issue. As you said, a simple (single layer) perceptron does not have the representational power to capture XOR.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Btw, do you have any resource that contains a numerical example of delta rule. Asking a new question for this doesn't look appropriate.

Comment: Do you mean MADALINE can be used?

Comment: @VIPULTYAGI MADALINE seems to be a specific architecture of MLP that uses ADALINE units. I guess it could work? What I meant is using multiple layers in general: instead of a single layered perceptron, introduce hidden layers to obtain an MLP.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvXgjETpDpk this video features a numerical example of the delta rule. P.S.: please consider accepting/upvoting my answer, thanks :)